# 10m air pistol target detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I want to detect [10m air pistol target](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_meter_air_pistol#/media/File:10_meter_air_pistol_target.svg) from many perspectives and fixed distance. Perspectives will be from -30˚ to 30˚.

After detection, I want to fix perspective. So that means I want to get 4 corners points which could be used for fixing perspective.

I am using [standard target](http://www.acme-firearms.com.au/Shooting%20Targets/krueger-paper-shooting-ISSF-targets/3000.jpg) for testing purpose.

I have a little experience of OpenCV. So I'll be glad if someone gave me right approach.

Comment: Can you share some real world input images.

Comment: There is no right approach. Each CV task is dependent on the input image properties and task properties/priorities... You can adapt this [Detecting circles and shots from paper target](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30423755/2521214)

Comment: These are [input images](http://imgur.com/a/w0I7q).
And I have few ideas to detect 4 corners.
1. Rectangle detecting. Problem is background is not fixed, it can contain any color and shape

Comment: 2. Feature matching. Our targets can be little different

Comment: I would start with remowing all non-white and non-black pixels ...